# SonarQube analysis fails after upgrade to 3.7.1 rules

Tags: sonarqube

Using SonarQube 5.2 - just the "click and go" distribution downloaded yesterday and running under Windows. Nothing fancy.

After upgrading the "Java" rules package from the bundled 3.6 version to 3.7.1, the sonar runner then fails during analysis.

There's a long stacktrace that is revealed when running with '-e' option however there is no detail on where in the file it failed (line-number, method) or which rule failed.

I have pared down the stack-trace to what I believe are the useful bits:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
...
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'C:\Users\robert.rusk\Documents\cvs\ip_probe\src\com\robert\splat\MyClass.java'
...
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index (1) must be less than size (1)
...
        at org.sonar.java.checks.PrintfCheck.verifyParameters(PrintfCheck.java:173)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.PrintfCheck.onMethodInvocationFound(PrintfCheck.java:112)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encoutering the following issue : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1369
It happens when you have a parameter with `%<` during the printf check (rule squid:S2275).

Issue has been fixed (few minutes ago for the record ;) ) and should be part of next release bound to happen within the next few days.

Comment: Thanks :) I think this type of failure would be easier to manage if more context was provided as to where the failure occurred. Is there a ticket open to add this kind of information upon failure? Currently just the filename ...

Comment: Those failures are unexpected issues so it is pretty hard to actually pinpoint at which point during the analysis of the file the issue happened.

Comment: yes, it is something that I would describe as a "new feature" under the heading "usability" :-)

Comment: The thing is that it is not doable in every cases. And a too huge effort that would end mess up the code for small added value. (not that usability is not valuable, but ROI of such a feature is really low).

Comment: also notable is that `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2275")` does not suppress execution of this faulty rule.

Comment: Suppress warning will only act on reporting of issue, not execution of the rule.

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation I now believe the error occurs because `String.format` is called without enough parameters (should be 2), and when I comment out this line the analysis then runs without any problems.

```
splatDateStr = String.format("%tFT%<tRZ", splatDate);
```

I guess this is the `PrintfCheck` that is referred to in the stack-trace.

Comment: Reviewing the documentation for String.format I see that the number of parameters is correct. As @benzonico says it's to do with how `%<` is interpreted, which means it should use the same parameter again.